# A question of congruence modulo concept. (Optimization Required)

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, modular-arithmetic

I have an arr[] of M integers. He has to find all integers K such that :

1)  K > 1
2) arr[1]%K = arr[2]%K = arr[3]%K = ... = arr[M]%K where '%' is a modulus operator

with following constraints :
- 2<= M <=100
- 1< value of each integer <109
- All integers will be distinct

I have written an algorithm and program for this problem. Here is my code: `

```
 int main()
 {

  std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

  int M;
  cin>>M;
  long long int arr[M];
  long long int max = LLONG_MIN;
  for(int i=0; i<M; i++)
  { 
    cin>>arr[i];
    if(max<arr[i])
    {
        max=arr[i];
    }
 }
 vector<long long int> vec;
 for(int k=2; k<max/2; k++)
 {
    bool flag = true;
    int result = arr[0]%k;
    for(int j=1; j<M; j++)
    {
        if(result != arr[j]%k)
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag == true)
    {
        vec.push_back(k);
    }
 }

 for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
 {
    cout<<vec[i]<<" ";
 }
 return 0;
```

}

But in worst case my code will run in O(n^2) which is having quadratic time complexity. Please suggest some of the optimization which I can do.

Comment: The start of this post could use some formatting, e.g. in $\TeX$ or using `code tags`.  Also, you don't need to do stuff like `if(flag == true)`; `if(flag)` is sufficient since the `flag`'s already a `true`/`false` value.

Comment: Code doesn't belong here. Please describe your algorithm more succinctly in pseudocode.